# Play game services: The application is incorrectly configured error?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, android-sdk-tools

I have integrated the google play game services to my app and also i have deplyoed the app in the playstore for aplha testing. I have also added the proper email id for tester and also i have properly configured the SHA5 for the same. But i'm getting the error as shown in the below screen shot.

[image: screenshot]

I can see the below logs in the android studio logcat

```
**** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: ****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: ****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: ****     a test account.
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: ****
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** To help you debug, here is the information about this app
11-01 11:08:56.669 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** Package name         : com.purvotara.makeit24
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: 27:EF:8E:62:7E:34:8E:B2:C6:47:A2:57:A9:EB:99:70:AC:40:D2:B2
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** App ID from          : 978150775748
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: ****
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** Check that the above information matches your setup in 
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** Developer Console. Also, check that you're logging in with the
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** right account (it should be listed in the Testers section if
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** your project is not yet published).
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: ****
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: **** For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
11-01 11:08:56.670 9353-9353/com.purvotara.makeit24 W/GameHelper: ****   http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting
```

Please help in fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you to solve in generating build :

The signature you uploaded in the developer console is matched with your signed build signature.

Use the same signature which is uploaded in the developer console. or else change the information in developer console.

`NOTE : Signature in developer console should match the signature which is configured in your android studio build settings. Then only you can able to upload the signed and production build to a marketplace.`

Comment: Thanks for the replying. Can you please elaborate. Where would i find the signature? If found, should i copy the signature from dev console to local project.